# I want to implement a distributed workflow system like Dophin scheduler with actor model, is there any mature actor model support java? only akka?

Tags: java, akka, workflow, actor

someone say Akka is not the best choice for handling workflows. it is right?

is there any other mature distributed actor model support java?

is the vertx more suitable for this scenario? How is the performance of akka compared to vertx?

Comment: This isn't really a good StackOverflow question. It's way to broad and opinion focused. But, while the question is open, Akka isn't a workflow engine but is a *great* framework to build a workflow system upon. (Because of how it manages state.)

Comment: The wikipedia page for Actor Systems lists lots of implementations, including many for Java. Akka is almost certainly the most mature though.

Comment: Vert.x isn't a complete actor system, but it's similar functionality and you could certainly build a workflow/scheduler on Vert.x as well. Both Vert.x and Akka are blazing fast: it's hard to compare their performance apples to apples but both have very low overhead. Performance for both is much higher than you will need it to be and you should choose between them based on their APIs/functionality rather than performance.